# Could we have independent browser CSS in Next JS

Tags: css, next.js, webkit

If I write the CSS as `style jsx` in Next JS, do I need to write all browser supports manually in my styles or Next JS add them automatically during build time for the production?
for example:

```
transofm:translate(50%,50%)
-webkit-transofm:translate(50%,50%)  // such line will be added automatically during build time?
```

......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not add them automatically for CSS in JS by default, but Next.js uses PostCSS by default with Autoprefixer plugin (you should have a *postcss.config.js* file in your root dir), so you can use [postcss-js](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js) (also mentioned in [autoprefixer docs](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#css-in-js))

Default behavior of PostCSS in Next: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config

Comment: It looks too much work for something that should be done automatically I guess!